# Initialize enum variable in header

Tags: c++

I'm creating a new enum:

```
enum WState {SLEEPING=2, WAITING_FOR_DATA=3, SENDING=4, IDLE=5, ERROR=6};
```

Then I'm trying to initialize a variable of that enum type to a default state straight after.

```
WState CurrentState = WState::ERROR;
```

I can't figure out the correct syntax or maybe I'm missing some vital keywords when searching for an answer. It says:

> data member initializer not allowed

[image]

Comment: your answer is C++ rule: "data member initializer not allowed"

Comment: Data member initializer is a C++11 feature. Have you enabled support for that?

Comment: Oh I misread. So there's an instance variable which you're trying to initialize, I see.

Comment: Move the initialization to the class constructor.

Comment: Also, enums don't define their own namespaces : you want `Wireless::ERROR` instead of `WState::ERROR`. `WState::ERROR` in this case will be allowed only because of a Microsoft-specific compiler extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, what you are doing is allowed. In C++03, however, you have to perform the initialization in the class constructor (possibly in an initialization list, as shown below):

```
class Wireless
{
public:
    enum WState { /* ... */, ERROR = 6 };
    WState CurrentState;
    Wireless() : CurrentState(WState::ERROR)
    { /* ... */ }

    // ...
};
```